# Need to find and extract matching 'Names' from 2 different Name columns of 2 different Data Frames in R

Tags: r, match, character

I am new to R & need a bit of guidance here, my problem is like this:
I have 2 dfs on both dfs I have performed series of operations and I need to perform this operation in the end

df1 & df2

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","F","G","s","x")) 
#(1)

df1$newname <-  c("A","V","C","D","c","v","x") #(name extracted from other column) (2)

df2 <- data.frame(Id_name = c("A","B","C","s","s", "x","G", "g"))
#(3)
```

Step1 = I need to match 2 with 3 first and extract common names, let's name it 4

Step2 = find names in 4 that have duplicate value = 1

Step3 = delete those values from 1 and 3

I tried using anti_join and semi_join but I guess that works for numeric values only, Is there any specific library available for this and how to solve this

Comment: I have tried using lib(compare) also I can find df$tm to get few names but cant resolve the problem I am facing

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible? Add some mock data and what is the result you're expecting. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more information on how to do just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategy followed below relies on `intersect`/extraction:

1. Get the common names with `intersect`.
2. Remove the `df1$name` that can be found in `common`.
3. Do as point 2, this time with `df2$Id_name`.

It is fully vectorized, no need for joins.
Note also argument `drop = FALSE`. The examples posted in the question have only one column, and with the default `drop = TRUE` the results would loose the `dim` attribute, becoming vectors.

```
common <- intersect(newname, df2$Id_name)
df1 <- df1[!df1$name %in% common, , drop = FALSE]
df2 <- df2[!df2$Id_name %in% common, , drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: Please check just edited my post, @Rui- Thanks a ton, I guess this logic should work.

Comment: @rajeshdhingra Done, see how it is now.

Comment: yes thanks again , got the result, but just a point to make, is "intersect" here doing exact match(case sensitive) ?, IMO it is doing that, is there any option for partial match or any other option which can ignore lower/upper case (Just asking for gaining insights and for any future use)

Comment: @rajeshdhingra `intersect(tolower(newname), tolower(df2$Id_name))`. But then you will have to do the same in the next instructions `tolower(df1$name)` and `tolower(df2$Id_name)`, or, simpler, do it all before and work with the data sets in lower case.

Comment: Ok sure will do that and check the results, @Rui Barradas Thank You very much.